# How to do searches in MediaWiki mode?

Tags: search, minor-mode

How to do searches in [MediaWiki mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MediaWikiMode)?  If I instead do searches in Web browser, and then copy the URI of the page into Emacs, it sort of defeats the purpose of using Emacs as and MediaWiki power editor or IDE.

Use case description:

I open Emacs with Mediawiki mode, and connect and login to wikipedia.org.  I want to search for an existing article whose title is roughly Mao Zedong.  I know there must be an article about the person, but the title may have a small difference.  In Web browser, searching "Ma Zedong" will go to this page if it's the exact title, or a list of found results that has titles close to my search term.  What's the equivalent process in Emacs?