# Writing helm search for MediaWiki-powered wikis

Tags: helm, search, helm-sources

Related: [How to do searches in MediaWiki mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/how-to-do-searches-in-mediawiki-mode)

In the absence of specific support for searching MediaWiki sites, `helm` seems like a good framework for search and navigation.

How does one write a helm extension for WikiMedia-powered wikis? Is this even generalizable across wikis in the helm framework?